# keeping only first value of every minute in table

Tags: sqlite

i have a huge table called "eFact" with timestamps and values
example:

```
ts                  value
__________________________
20221018080350000   22756.9
20221018080354028   22756.9
20221018080357831   22756.9
20221018080401000   22756.9
20221018080404000   22756.9
20221018080407458   22756.9
20221018080411000   22756.9
20221018080414067   22756.9
20221018080417000   22756.9
20221018080421000   22756.9
```

the problem is that i only need the first row per minute
so that the table looks like this:

```
20221018080350000   22756.9
20221018080401000   22756.9
```

is this even possible?
thanks for your help

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `ts` is a string value, but solution can be easily adapted for other data types.

You can group timestamps using the first characters up to the minute, then extract the first timestamp for each minute and the value corresponding to such timestamp.

```
SELECT MIN(ts), value
FROM eFact
GROUP BY SUBSTR(ts,1,12)
ORDER BY ts
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/toY5XWAO)

This only works in Sqlite, which [allows for using non-aggregate result colums which are not part of the GROUP BY clause](https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html#aggregate_queries_can_contain_non_aggregate_result_columns_that_are_not_in_the_group_by_clause).

Comment: @J.D. I interpreted the question to require the first value in any given minute, even if there are different values in the same minute. Using an aggregate on value, such as min(), max() or avg() would not be coherent with the returned timestamp. In such case returning only SUBSTR(ts,1,12) AS timestamp would be more correct.

Comment: To be clearer: With SQLite if an aggregate query contains a single min() or max() function, then the values of columns used in the output are taken from the row where the min() or max() value was achieved.

Comment: @J.D. The same docs state that _if an aggregate query contains a single min() or max() function, then the values of columns used in the output are taken from the row where the min() or max() value was achieved._ Since we take `min(ts)`, then `value` is taken from the same row where min(ts) is taken (the one with the minimum ts in the group).

Comment: [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/bKvAJaaB) is a fiddle with different values, inserted in the table in a different order, that still returns the correct answer.

Comment: Sorry you're right. I overlooked that part of the docs relative to your query. I know other database systems have different implementations of this as well. I personally still think it's better practice to be explicit in general, but your answer will indeed deterministically solve OP's problem. That's cool in a niche way in SQLite. +1.